# How to solve this integral? This one is the hardest!

Tags: calculus

Integrate $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^7-1}{\log x} \, \mathrm{d}x$$!It's from MIT integration bee

I try to solve this by substitution but nothing works out. Solving this problem from 10 days .I have no idea how they have a answer $\log(8)$.

Comment: can you use $\LaTeX$ please!

Comment: And what are the limits of integration?

Answer (score 11):

The trick we use is differentiating under the integral sign.

Define $$F(k) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^k - 1}{\log(x)}dx$$

Then,
$$\frac{\partial F(k) }{\partial k}= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^k \log(x) }{\log(x)}dx =\int_{0}^{1}x^k dx= \frac{1}{k+1}$$

Our original integral can be retrieved by integrating with respect to $k$ and setting $k=7$:
$$F(7) = \int_{0}^{7}\frac{1}{k+1}dk = \log(8)$$

Comment: Parametric integration really ought to be taught more widely in, say, second-semester calculus along with the usual "techniques of integration".  It is simple enough conceptually and is just too darn _useful_ to set aside "for later".

Comment: What is the justification for interchanging the order of integration and differentiation here?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign for a formal proof and many examples

Comment: A short sentence about the differentiation through the integral would have been nice. +1 anyway.

Comment: This reminds me of something that would be found in the "handbook of integration" a few mits putt outfit a few years ago.

Comment: That should be "put out."